# Parsing program: How am I loading my object incorrectly?

Tags: php, syntax, logic, undefined, fgets

In my opinion, the `if (isStart($line)){}` and `if (isEnd($line))` blocks put things into the wrong scope.  The problem area is commented around "`/***PROBLEM AREA */`".

This is my parsing program:

```
<?php

  //**CLASS AND OBJECT */
  class Entry
  {
    private $reason;
    private $s_id;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->reason     = '';
      $this->s_id       = '';
    }

      //** GETTERS AND SETTERS */
    public function SetReason($reason)
    {
      $this->reason = $reason;
    }

    public function GetReason()
    {
      return $this->reason;
    }

    public function SetS_id($s_id)
    {
      $this->s_id = $s_id;
    }

    public function GetS_id()
    {
      return $this->s_id;
    }
  }

  //** EXTRACTION FUNCTION(S)
  function extractReason($line)
  {
    $matches;
    preg_match('/^Reason:\s+(.*)\s+$/', $line, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
  }  

  function extractS_id($line)
  {
    $matches;
    preg_match('/^S_id:\s+(.*)\s+$/', $line, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
  }

  //** LINE CONTAINST DESIRED EXTRACTION CHECK */
  function isStart($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^Start$/', $line);
  }

  function isReason($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^Reason:\s+(.*)$/', $line);
  }

  function isS_id($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^S_id:\s+(.*)$/', $line);
  }

  function isContent($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/.*$/', $line);
  }

  function isEnd($line)
  {
    return preg_match('/^End$/', $line);
  }




  //** DEFINITION */
  $fName = 'obfile_extractsample.txt';
  $fh    = fopen($fName, 'r');
  $line;
  $entry;
  $entrys = array();

  //** PARSE OPERATION
  if ($fh === FALSE)
    die ('Failed to open file.');

  //**START PROBLEM AREA */
  while (($line = fGets($fh)) !== FALSE)
  {
    if (isStart($line)){
      $entry = new Entry();
      if (isReason($line)){
        $entry->SetReason(extractReason($line));
      }
      if (isS_id($line)){
        $entry->SetS_id(extractS_id($line));
      }
      if (isEnd($line)){
        $entrys[] = $entry;
      }
    }
  }
  //***END PROBLEM AREA */

  echo "<pre>";
    print_r($entrys);
  echo "</pre>";
  fclose($fh);

?>
```

This is my example file:

```
Start
Name:      David Foster  
Out Time:  4:36 p.m.    
Back Time: 4:57 p.m.
Reason:    Lunch
S_id:      0611125
End

Start
Name:      Brenda Banks  
Out Time:  5:53 a.m.    
Back Time: 6:30 a.m.
Reason:    Personal
S_id:      0611147
End
```

This is the output:

```
Array()
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

The regex string input in the `isStart` and `isEnd` functions was incorrect.  There were some invisible symbols before the end of the line.  The correct regex patterns are: `'/^Start.*$/'` and `'/^End.*$/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit:

```
    if (isContent($line)){
      $entry = new Entry();
      $entry->SetReason(extractReason($line));
      $entry->SetS_id(extractS_id($line));
      $entrys[] = $entry;
    }
```

will always create a new `Entry` and add it to your array, but the only fields it can detect are `Reason: ...` and `Style: ...`. So most of the lines result in empty `Entry`s.

Comment: Yeah, I only want `Reason: ` and `S_id: `, but the output is all messed up.  The output should be like this: http://pastebin.com/RnaieuyA.  There are too many results, the preg_match() patterns are wrong, and the results are arrays of 2.  I should output `$match[1]`, but it throws a ton of errors: `undefined offset 1`.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: As I said, you're creating a new `Entry` for each line. Instead, you need to create one `Entry` before you enter the loop, and then create a new `Entry` each time you detect a blank line. (But note that there's a bug in `isContent`: it will always return `1`. You'll need to fix that before you can get the other stuff working.)

Comment: ruakh, I should put `$entry = new Entry();` outside of the `if block`?

Comment: The reason I wanted `isContent` to return `1` is because I wanted to check every line.  I see what you mean, though.

Comment: Well, one thing I noticed is that the line has to end with a return, otherwise it won't pick up a match.  Something I'm worried about is having `$entrys[]` and `$entry = new Entry();` in with the `if blocks`.  What if one or both of these is not a primary key?  In most cases, only one primary key will exist.

Comment: Here's a solution I've tried: http://pastebin.com/ku0xjrGN.  Unfortunately, the result is blank.